# What is this Disney scifi movie from the late 80s/early 90s?

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid we had a VHS tape of some Disney live action (not animated) sci-fi movie. It may have been a mini-series or a made-for-tv movie, but I'm not sure. I'm also not sure about the year but it would probably have been late 80s or early 90s based on when I would have seen it. I know it was Disney because they had some live action Goofy and Mickey running around the movie's set as an introduction discussing the plot with a host before the movie.

The plot is basically as follows:

1. A starship is loaded with mostly children and teenagers as a cross-galaxy human settling effort.
2. Accidents (which are not really accidents and later revealed) cause adult crew members to be killed.
3. They travel to another planet and face all sorts of troubles.
4. It arrives at the new planet after overcoming obstacles.

Other memorable scenes that may help:

- Navigating out of earth's asteroid belt made out of space junk.
- One of the adults was killed via an airlock malfunction.
- The ship was supposed to be peaceful with no weapons. At one point they bring on board some crazy guy who puts together a rail gun. There's a memorable line like "Do you want no weapons at all or a well aimed rock?"
- There's a planet or space station (I can't remember which) that has a fight scene with the evil bad guy. This scene takes place on what looks to be a carnival or fairground.
- The bad guys are trying to steal the ship the kids are on because it has some kind of really good futuristic space drive.

Hopefully you remember it better than I do! I've tried looking online for it before with no luck.

Comment: Am I the only one whose first thought was "That sounds like Pandorum!"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*[Earth Star Voyager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)*

More details are available at [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095077/maindetails) and you can watch the full movie below.