# Movie from the 70s or 80s that had a Cyborg

Tags: story-identification, cyborg

I've been looking for a movie that I saw when I was growing up. Here's what I remember from it:

- There was a cyborg (or cyborgs)
- I think at some point the main cyborg was conflicted between being the bad guy and good guy (this one may just be a figment of me trying to remember it so many times).
- It's possible that one of his eyes was a light
- They were on some sort of space station/spaceship

If I saw a screenshot or scene I think I'd remember it but I've looked for a couple years and haven't had any luck. I'm guessing that I saw it in the late 80s or early 90s on TV so it might have been a 70s or 80s film.

Comment: This sounds a bit like like the Universal Solder Series with Jean-Claude Van Damme and Dolph Lundgen in which they were brought back as reanimated soldier/cyborgs.  Though the movie came out a bit later in 1992, not the 80s. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Soldier_(franchise)

The IMDB site shows a movie poster of Van Damme with a prosthetic eye. 

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105698/

Comment: @beichst: I‘ve been trying to think of that since I saw this question, thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-this-disney-scifi-movie-from-the-late-80s-early-90s

Comment: @Otis: Only if confirmed, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be [Earth Star Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)?

It's from 1988 and contains many of the features you've mentioned including a cyborg with a light for an eye and a spaceship.

[image: Closeup of a person's head, with dark hair and a strong chin, facing upward, looking to its right. The skin of the left side of the face from the cheekbone to the brow ridge is missing, and a metal skeleton shows underneath. The eye socket is a glowing disk.]

**You can watch the full movie online below:**

Answer (score 2):

I suspect (mainly because I have no better ideas) that you're thinking of the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episodes ["The Best of Both Worlds", part 1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds_(episode)) and [part 2](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds,_Part_II_(episode)) from 1990; while not a movie, when broadcast on TV with commercials, it is an hour per episode.  [The guys who put the "Borg" in "cyborg"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg) kidnap the starship's captain and turn him into one of their own, and while he doesn't get a light for an eye, [he does get a light *next to* an eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXs0R.png).  At the end, the ship's crew have to hack into his systems and get him to remember them and turn back to good, and he has to fight against his cyborg implants to meet them halfway.