# Series or miniseries about four or five kids/teens on spaceship to be turned into cyborgs

Tags: story-identification

Once I saw a series or a movie split into approx. 3-6 parts, where the main characters were four or five kids/teenagers and they somehow managed to get on a spaceship that was supposed to go into deep space or maybe some constellation. On route they discovered there was some sort of plan to turn them into cyborgs. I have no idea what country filmed it but i guess it was shot sometime between 1985 - 1995. Any ideas? The question has been chasing me for years:)

Thanks

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-this-disney-scifi-movie-from-the-late-80s-early-90s

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [Earth Star Voyager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)? It aired in 1988 as a two-part pilot. The primary crew are teenagers and young adults. Their mission is to a distant Earthlike planet. Also, there are cyborgs involved, though I'm not sure if you could characterize it as a plot to turn the kids into cyborgs.

Apparently, the full movie is on YouTube: