# Deep space voyage with cryosleep and murder

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a sci fi movie from the 80s or 90s.

The crew headed out on a mission into deep space. When on Earth in the beginning they used a breathing apparatus and they went to a fast food stand and one of them ordered a hamburger. Then there was cryosleep and murder on the voyage.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Cryosleep and shipboard murders are pretty common themes. In addition to the breathing apparatus and hamburger scene is there anything else you might remember about the movie? E.g. presumably it was in English. Did you see it on TV, in a theater, on VCR?  Anything about the ship itself you might remember or how the crew member was murdered?  Thanks.

Comment: Definitely in English.  I believe I saw it on TV at home rather than in a theater.  The hamburger may have been a distinctive color, maybe blue?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-this-disney-scifi-movie-from-the-late-80s-early-90s

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like it's [Earth Star Voyager](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095077/).

From the [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager):

> Earth Star Voyager is the name of a science fiction television movie
>   shown on the Wonderful World of Disney in 1988. The show aired as a
>   two-part pilot, but was never picked up for a series and has not been
>   released on DVD, although a fan base for the pilot has grown over the
>   years

The Wikipedia article has a [much longer plot synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager#plot).

The "hamburger" in question was called a "veggie bio burger." Before dispensing it, the computer scanned your hand. This not only used your palmprint to access your bank account, but also scanned your body for your current metabolic state. The "burger" was tailored to your nutritional needs at that exact moment.

Comment: I remember that one! One of the kids couldn't get it to scan, so his fellow cadet used their palm to get it for him. They later had some scene where they had to duck under the eyebeam of some robots against a wall. I was thinking it might be a match, as I remembered the burger scene, but I was convinced that was the old Battlestar Galactica.

Comment: Veggie bio burger? Wow, prophetic!

Comment: What an utterly bad series it was too...

Comment: That was it....  Earth Star Voyager.  You just solved a mystery that was haunting me for 28 years.  Thank you.