# What was the name of a series about young adults or teenagers traveling away from earth after it's either been destroyed or infected with a virus

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship

I remember watching a series (or maybe a movie) about young adults or teenagers traveling away from Earth to try and find another planet to colonize after Earth has either been destroyed or infected with a virus. It's from either the 90s or early 2000s. The majority of the series is on their ship I think. It's definitely not [Earth Star Voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-this-disney-scifi-movie-from-the-late-80s-early-90s). I think it might have been a Disney series but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This may be [Mission Genesis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118403/) from 1997 (Original title: [Deepwater Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_Black)).
This was the Sci-Fi Channel's first original series.
It was yanked after thirteen episodes.

> A virus breaks out and leaves the humans residing on Earth doomed.
> However, in a desperate attempt before the end, all humanity's
> resources are dedicated to a crash program to produce a deep space
> ark, capable of seeding humanity on a new world. The ship is crewed by
> six clones; teenage versions of people who achieved great works during
> the ark project and equipped with the memories of their donors. Prior
> to its arrival, however, the crew is awoken prematurely to face a
> threat to the ship, before their memories are complete. They must come
> to terms with the workings of the ship, the dangers faced by their
> ship, the realization that they are clones, and their ultimate destiny
> to save their race.

Soon after production ended, lead actress [Nicole de Boer](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0207498/?ref_=tt_cl_t_2) joined the cast of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine and lead actor [Gordon Michael Woolvett](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0941315/?ref_=tt_cl_t_1) joined the cast of Andromeda.

Comment: Yes! That's it. I thought it was just some fever dream. Thank you. :D

Comment: Wow, could a show *get* any more 90s? That cover looks like a No Doubt album art.

Comment: Did they change the name when they realized that "dWb" reads as "dweeb"? :-(

Answer (score 10):

In the mid-late 90's the Sci-Fi channel produced a show they called Mission Genesis (based on a book series called Deepwater Blue; the same show was called Deepwater Black on YTV), it revolved around teenage human clones flying a spaceship to find a new homeworld after Earth's population was wiped out from some sort of plague/biological weapon (I'm not sure which).