# I remember a Sat morning sci fi show in the 70’s or 80’s that feature an all teenage crew made up of very intelligent individuals

Tags: story-identification, tv

The crew was young because they needed to be in space a long time for what ever their mission was. The capt/cmdr was a dark-haired/white male and he had a smaller reddish haired/white male assistant. The both sat in beanbag chair-like things in the cmd area/bridge. The ship’s surgeon was a white/blonde female and the ship’s psychologist was a light brown-haired/white male. This guy was sneaky. There were other crew as well.

Comment: I think the question would be more interesting (for potential answers) if you described more about the plot and less about the chairs and hair color -- right? What interested you about the show to want to know its name 40 or 50 years on? I watched too much TV as a kid and what u said does not ring a bell.

Comment: @releseabe - Different people focus on different things. Padmé was given ten different sets of clothing for a reason. I barely noticed them, but female audience-goers rated her outifts as one of the main things they liked about the prequel films.

Comment: @releseabe - It would be nice to have more plot-related details, but as someone who answers a lot of story-ID questions, I find visual details very helpful when searching for prospective answers. They often help me tell at a glance whether an IP that I've found is a potential match or not. Also, the OP in this case may have told us everything they recall in respect to the plot.

Comment: What country did you view it in and on what channel? What did the outside of the ship they wee on look like?

Comment: @LogicDictates and Valorum: I understand but I assume stuff happened in the show. For example, there was no episode where they acquire the chairs -- we just accept that they had them. I am prompting the OP to come up with some intriguing stuff in addition to furniture and hair color -- I am not criticizing but trying to help. Nothing wrong with chairs; I just want to know more.

Comment: Was this a cartoon or live-action show?

Comment: @MeatTrademark: I bet a cartoon -- how many live-action shows could afford beanbag chairs??

Comment: Look up the animated versions of Lost in Space and Fatanstic Voyage. I don't see any beanbags but a sneaky psychologist might be a Dr. Smith clue.  And you may be combining them too.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Which reminds me, Jonathan Harris (who played Dr.Smith on _Lost in Space_) was in the late 1970's Saturday Morning TV show _[Space Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Academy)_.  This isn't a perfect match but is pretty darn close.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you're remembering [Earth Star Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager), a two-part Disney mini series from 1988 that was a stealth pilot for a tv series that never got picked up.

The premise is that in the future, the Earth has become almost uninhabitable because of pollution and ecological collapse - acid rain storms are common, the air is so foul people carry personal oxygen tanks to help them breath, and so on. The eponymous starship is being built to survey a promising planet in another star system to see if it's habitable and suitable for colonization. Once they launch, though, they quickly learn that things are not what they seem and shadowy powers have other plans for the ship...

Because the mission will take years, most of the crew is young, in their teens or early twenties. Some of them include:

- Captain Jake Brown, one of the few older adults - not originally assigned to the ship, but they rescue him from a derelict space station and he quickly assumes a leadership role. Dark hair and a beard.
- Command Specialist Jonathan Hays, brunette.
- His best friend, computer science guy Jessie Beinstock, short and red-haired.
- Ship's doctor Sally Anderson, a blonde.
- Psychiatrist Leland Eugene, brunette, a man who some of the crew think is up to something.

The [opening credits](https://youtu.be/WFgLL8EN71I) on Youtube feature them and other members of the crew.

Comment: The full movie is also on Youtube, but of dubious legality, so I'm not linking to any of those instances.

Comment: If so, it will be one of many dupes of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-this-disney-scifi-movie-from-the-late-80s-early-90s?noredirect=1&lq=1