A 90s (maybe) made-for-TV movie (maybe) about a group of trainees on a spaceship. There is some kind of emergency and all experienced officers die
After the death of the officers, the trainees have to get the ship to a certain planet/base to warn them of an attack. One of the trainees betrays/sabotages the others and the one in command ends up executing them during the journey.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   How did the officers all die?  How did they execute the saboteur?

Could it be Star Command (1996)?

@Pamphile I just posted my answer, and then saw your comment.  It definitely is.

Don't think this is it, but its rather similar to the plot of the 2009 "Star Trek" reboot movie. At least as I remember it.

Is this Earth Star Voyager (1988)...?
From TV Tropes:

Earth☆Star Voyager is a Pilot Movie that originally aired as a 2-part miniseries on ABC's The Disney Sunday Movie in January 1988. It focuses on a group of over-achieving young people from a late 21st century Crapsack Earth as they trek through the stars to find a new home for the human race. Along the way, the crew has to deal with the usual dangers of TV space travel, along with the drama and awkwardness typical of being a teenager or a young adult on television.

In the year 2088, the Earth's deteriorating ecology is making the planet increasingly uninhabitable. A spacecraft named the Earth Star Voyager is being sent to a distant planet to see if it'd make a suitable new home for the human race.
Since the journey there and back is expected to take 26 years, nearly the entire crew selected for the mission are in their teens or early twenties, with the exception of Captain Forbes. However, Forbes is killed during an apparent mishap not long after departure, forcing his 21-year-old second-in-command, Jonathan Hayes, to take over.
Since Forbes' death appeared to be an accident, the remaining crew continue on their original mission. However, when another member of the crew ends up in a coma as a result of a malfunctioning cryo-sleep chamber, they start to suspect that there's a traitor on board.
Hayes eventually catches the traitor sabotaging one of the ship's weapons and is forced to eject that person through an airlock as an act of self-defence.
You can view the scene I just described at around the 1:03:46 mark in the video below, but be aware that it is obviously a spoiler for anyone who doesn't already know who the traitor is.




If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-this-disney-scifi-movie-from-the-late-80s-early-90s?noredirect=1&lq=1 As you can see, it comes up fairly often. :) It was a bit of Core memory for me.

This sounds like Star Command (also known as In the Fold).  Quotations below are from the linked Wikipedia article's plot summary.
A 90s (maybe) made-for-TV movie (maybe)...

Star Command (secondary title In the Fold) is a 1996 television film... which was originally intended as a television pilot...

...about a group of trainees on a spaceship.

...a class of graduating cadets is assigned...a training cruise on the corvette Surprise, in the company of only two experienced officers...

There is some kind of emergency and all experienced officers die.

The Surprise...is...ambushed...[and]...both of the ship's officers are lost in action...

After the death of the officers, the trainees have to get the ship to a certain planet/base to warn them of an attack.

...the Cynosurans are...planning to exterminate the 25,000 Earth colonists on Meraz, [so the trainees]...vote to relaunch the ship and do everything possible to prevent the attack.

One of the trainees betrays/sabotages the others and the one in command ends up executing them during the journey.*

Ensign Jackson protests the decision... He is outvoted... The disgruntled Jackson attempts to seize control of the ship... Afterward the trainees carry out a makeshift court-martial, at which Jackson is sentenced to death by unanimous secret vote...


Could it have been "Lifepod".  The timeframe is right and some of the details would seem to match.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifepod_(1993_film)

I've seen  this film and described some of the plot in this previous answer. As far as this question goes, most of the people who make it into the lifepod are passengers, not trainee crew members. At least two people in the group are crew members -- one a bridge officer and the other a mechanic -- but they're both experienced. Plus, calling a lifepod a spaceship feels like a stretch. The actual spaceship they escaped from is destroyed near the beginning.
